# How do I maintain Python packages on OS X Lion?

Tags: python, installation, package, osx-mountain-lion

What is the correct way to install and update Python packages on OS X Mountain Lion, using Apple's built in Python?

I've tried all everything I can find here and in the documentation for various packages but keep encountering all kinds of errors that result in failed or aborted installations or updates. Notably, with `pip` I frequently get errors like

> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp

or

> SError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'

and some commands `pip` commands (like `list`) just don't seem to exist at all.

I have an uptodate version of `pip` that works fine with some packages, and have the latest Xcode command line tools installed.

The only thing that seems to work — and it works all the time — is

```
python setup.py install
```

Is this the correct way to maintain and install python packages on Lion? Is there any reason *not* to use this method as my primary method for keeping packages uptodate? Should `pip` be working for me, or does it not work with Apple's Python?

---

**UPDATE:** I spoke too soon. I also have problems with

```
python setup.py install
```

Occasionally (often) I'll get:

> error: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages: Too many open files

When nothing is running in a fresh Terminal, I get about 50 when I

```
lsof | grep python | wc -l
```

and if I quit Dropbox, which seems to be the source of these, and reduce the number to 0, I still get "Too many open files" for most package installation operations, with whatever tool I use, even after a reboot of my system.

*Why am I getting a "too many open files" error so often?*

Comment: To be clear, this question has two parts: (1) should `pip` be working for me with **Apple Python** and (2) if this is a common problem, is `python setup.py install` a correct and reliable way to maintain an **Apple Python**. This is not a question about which other Python to use (though that's an interesting question).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to maintain exactly as you're doing, but likely need to update your PYTHONPATH to somewhere outside of /Library, hence the reason everyone else is mentioning that and/or using homebrew to install python.

I install python packages with `pip` and maintain them using:

https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools

Comment: If you use caps (old school) I'll accept this as the answer. It turned out to be nothing but a path problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, download and install the full Python from [the python website](https://www.python.org/downloads/).
Then use [`pip`](https://dubroy.com/blog/so-you-want-to-install-a-python-package/) (or [`homebrew`](https://brew.sh/)). The built-in python is incomplete in many respects, including mainly, the ability to install new packages. I faced similar problems when I fist got my MacBookPro and installing the full python on top of the built-in one solved all my troubles

Answer (score -1):

Why use Apple's built-in Python? It's incomplete, I think.

I'm using Homebrew and `brew install python` works fine for me.

From https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python:

> We recommend to `brew install python` because:
>
> - Comes with `pip` (and distribute)
> - Python (distutils) finds brewed
>     software (includes, libs), knows about the compiler and flags even if
>     the command line tools for Xcode are not installed.
> - No need to set the `PYTHONPATH` for Homebrew bindings.
> - No need to work-around the `sudo`-is-needed-for-`easy_install` issue

Comment: Using `brew install python` gives **"error: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages: Too many open files"**